# How to properly force HTTPS in SAFE-Stack?

Tags: f#, saturn-framework, safe-stack

As per [Saturn docs](https://saturnframework.org/docs/api/application/#force_ssl), to have HSTS in Saturn, one needs to specify `force_ssl` in the `application`:

```fs
application {
    url ("http://0.0.0.0:" + port.ToString() + "/")
    force_ssl
    ...
}
```

This works for the deployed version of the web, however it breaks local development. Server does not return responses, in the log it writes `Request redirected to HTTPS` and that's all.

Is it possible to force SSL and keep local dev convenient at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAFE-stack assumes usage of `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server` and that works as a proxy to the real server which means one needs to do some adjustments there as well.

So the webpack config should now have `https` in the `target` of the `proxy` section:

```js
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '/api/*': {
            target: 'https://localhost:<port>',
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
},
```

This is not enough - as per [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy), to avoid security exceptions, one needs to unset `secure` flag:

```js
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '/api/*': {
            target: 'https://localhost:<port>',
            secure: false,
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
},
```

And the last thing is to modify server `application` accordingly:

```fs
application {
    url ("https://0.0.0.0:" + port.ToString() + "/")
    force_ssl
    ...
```

That should do it both for dev and prod versions of the web.